# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Unbound breakpoint

Tags: c#, debugging, webforms, breakpoints, unbound

The breakpoints do not hit, not even one

[image]

I have tried:

1. Restarting
2. Uninstalling and Installing
3. Ending all the errors
4. Build, Rebuild and again and again and build is successful always
5. The project I took was from TFS Source control and everyone else's working
6. I also took same project locally and there too the breakpoints are not working
7. In other projects, the breakpoints are working and settings are same for debugging so I don't know the problem
8. The project is in C#, webforms

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: make a new solution file, sometimes there are some temp files which can cause the problem. the previous errors sometimes remain in temp files. this is is the best way if you can't clean the project